# External SCSS style file link to HTML

Tags: css, sass

I have one style file with .scss code and .scss extention , what is the best practice to implement this style  file to HTML?

Do I need to create another style file with .css extention and convert .scss file first to .css? do I need to use some software to do this? I understand style.scss file does not need to link in HTML file and only style.css will be linked in HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS (and by consequent SCSS) is different from regular CSS since SASS is a scripting language written in Ruby. HTML can't use a SCSS file, it has to be transformed to regular CSS using a compiler.

If you use VSCode just install `Live Sass Compiler` extension.

You can also install it through npm

```
npm install -g sass
```

You can visit [Sass website](https://sass-lang.com/install) to see all the way to install it

Answer (score 0):

This is really a question to google. You should compile your scss file into css file, which can be made with watcher or tasker. Look at webpack with sass or directly to sass installation page.